# Call Scalar Function From HANA Procedure

Tags: function, procedure, hana, scalar

​I have a function that is defined as:
​Where XXXXX is my schema YYYYY is my package.

```
PROCEDURE "XXXXX"."YYYYY.SPATIAL::SP_GA_PT_PATH_DISTANCE" (IN PID NVarChar(36)) 
LANGUAGE SQLScript
SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
--DEFAULT SCHEMA <default_schema_name>
AS
BEGIN
```

I want to call a function and assign the result to a variable, I have tried the following two ways:

```
intIntersect := XXXXX.YYYYY.SPATIAL::GA_INTERSECT (32.925148, -117.020051, 
                                                   32.924672, -117.019454,
                                                   32.924488, -117.020322,
                                                   32.924849, -117.019759);

​SELECT XXXXX.YYYYY.SPATIAL::GA_INTERSECT (32.925148, -117.020051, 
                                      32.924672, -117.019454,
                                      32.924488, -117.020322,
                                      32.924849, -117.019759) INTO intIntersect FROM DUMMY;
```

​I have played with different permutations of this, but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe as a `FUNCTION` is really a `PROCEDURE` in your code example.

These differ in the ways you can call either of them.
**Procedures** need to be called via the `CALL` statement.

**Functions** can either be used as *scalar function* in all places where you can use expressions (i.e. the *projection list* of a `SELECT`-statement) or, for *table-typed* functions, like a table in the `WHERE` condition.

The parameters handed over to the procedure seem to be a list of data items.
The general way to pass "lists" of parameters is to use a **table-type** parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "XXXXX"."YYYYY.SPATIAL::SP_GA_PT_PATH_DISTANCE" 
              (IN_PIDS TABLE (PID NVARCHAR(36)) )
       RETURNS TABLE (DISTANCES DECIMAL)
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT * FROM :IN_PIDS;
...
```